# シェルスクリプトで現在の時刻(hh:mm)を取得してif文で分岐

Tags: shellscript

シェルスクリプトで現在の時刻(hh:mm)を取得してif文で12:00～13:00の間かそうでないかで条件分岐するプログラムを書きたいです。

この場合、

```sh
seccion_time=date '+%h'
start_time=12:00
finish_time=13:00

if [ $seccion_time -gt $finish_time]; then
    if [  $seccion_time -lt $finish_time ]; then
        echo 処理開始
    fi
fi
```

これだとdate型のフォーマットが正しくなくて動かないので、正しいフォーマットやより良い書き方あればご指南お願いします。

Comment: 13:00 を含まない(`[12:00, 13:00)`)のであれば `if [ $(date '+%H') -eq 12 ];then ... fi` で良いかと。

Answer (score 1):

この回答は[metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis)さんのコメントを元にしたものです。

13:00を含まないなら

```sh
if [ $(date '+%H') -eq 12 ]; then
    echo '処理開始'
fi
```

で良いかと。

Answer (score 1):

時刻に : を含めなければそのまま数値として比較できます。

```sh
now=$(date '+%H%M')
start_time=1200
finish_time=1300

echo $now

if [ $now -ge $start_time -a $now -lt $finish_time ]; then
    echo 処理開始
fi
```